# Encode any String to fixed length which can Decoded back

Tags: string, algorithm, encoding, character-encoding, logic

Encode a string containing alphabet's , number's and special character's  to a **specified length**

I found a answer which allows to do this for **numbers only** : [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67680814/15597511)

Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67680814/15597511) be done for a string containing alphabet's , number's and special character's  to a **specified length**

---

Tried converting alphabet's and special character to **ascii value** to encode it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67680814/15597511) but couldn't find a way to **restore the string** back

---

How to achieve the title by making any changes in either [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67680814/15597511)

**OR**

convert the string data to ascii value and the encode the resulting data => then later decode it back to encoded string

Ex :

```
String abc = "8428:3209_JsOla";
abc="842858320995741157910897";


Encode "abc" using above algo's ( link attached )  //this part of the problem is solved
Using above algo's ( link attached ) Decodes the Encoded string back to "842858320995741157910897"  //this part of the problem is solved


then convert back "842858320995741157910897" => "8428:3209_JsOla" //this parts needs to be solved
```

Comment: What is the maximum size of the input string? What are the special characters you allow in the input (Unicode has thousands of special characters)?

Comment: @trincot the maximum size of input string is 10... 
special characters 

" : to @ ( 58 - 64 ascii value)  and 

[ to ` ( 91 - 96 ascii value ) and 

{ to ~ ( 123 - 126 ascii value ) "

Comment: Then why abc in the example is longer than 10?

Comment: actually i reduced few characters   ..which store the same date...but max length currently is 10

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I looked back at this question and decided to convert the input text into a "number" based on the character ranges (which ended up evaluating to just char codes 48 through 126) and also use an alphabet "from" and alphabet "to" setup to encode from one to another :D

```js
function makeAlphabet(chars){
  let str={__proto__:null}, ab=null;
  if(typeof chars==="string") ab=chars.split(''); //array from string
  else if(typeof chars[0]==="string") ab=chars; //already array
  else{
    ab=[] //array from array of character ranges
    for(let i=0;i<chars.length;i++){
      let [start,end]=chars[i];
      for(let j=start; j<=end; j++)
        ab.push(String.fromCharCode(j));
    }
  }
  
  //ab includes numeric keys with character values
  //str contains character keys with numeric values
  for(let i=0;i<ab.length;i++) str[ab[i]]=i;
  return {ab,str}
}
function integer(string,alphabet){
  if(typeof string==="number") return BigInt(string);
  if(typeof string==="bigint") return string;
  let int=0n
  for(let i=0;i<string.length;i++){
    int *= BigInt(alphabet.ab.length)
    int += BigInt(alphabet.str[string[i]])
  }
  return int
}

function encode(input,alphabetFrom,alphabetTo,minLength=0){
  let num=integer(input,alphabetFrom)
  let {length}=alphabetTo.ab, encoded=""
  while(num>0n){
    let mod=num%BigInt(length)
    encoded=alphabetTo.ab[mod]+encoded
    num-=BigInt(mod)
    num/=BigInt(length)
  }
  while(encoded.length<minLength)
    encoded=alphabetTo.ab[0]+encoded;
  return encoded
}
/*usage:
  encode('255',decimal,binary) === '11111111'
  encode('255',decimal,binary,10) === '0011111111'
  encode(  encode('255',dec,bin),  bin,dec) === '255'
  //yes, using the 2 alphabets in one way then switching the order can in a sense be encoding and decoding
*/
let hex=makeAlphabet('0123456789ABCDEF')
let dec=makeAlphabet('0123456789')
let oct=makeAlphabet('01234567')
let bs4=makeAlphabet('0123')
let bin=makeAlphabet('01')
//feel free to experiment



//now onto execution of your question
//setting alphabets
let encodingAlphabet=makeAlphabet([[48,126], [256,4098]]);
let decodingAlphabet=makeAlphabet([[48,126]]);

//examples
let encoded=encode("8428:3209_JsOla",decodingAlphabet,encodingAlphabet,10)
let decoded=encode(encoded,encodingAlphabet,decodingAlphabet)
console.log({encoded,decoded})
```